# Solr Query to display selected fields

Tags: solr, facet

I am using 'Facet' to find the count of top 3 most repeated words in a particular field say "msgs" which contains more than 10,000 records.
and I get the output similar to this.

word1  1600
word2  1536
word3   956

Now, along with the count, I want to display those particular fields which contain the above words. Any suggestions??

Comment: what do you want to do with fields? you want to specify faceting dynamically on some field?

Comment: No... I just want to display the fields along with the  word count that I get from the facet

Comment: so, you ask how to display response?

Comment: Yes.. I want to display the word count and the fields as well

Comment: are you sure it's a solr related question? you get XML or JSON response - then it's your job to properly display it

Comment: I am ok with displaying it  in JSON or XML format.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. I hope I understand what you need. You could try query similar to this one:

```
http://solrhost:solrport/solr/select?q=your_query&rows=0&facet=true&facet.limit=-1&facet.field=your_facet_field1&facet.field=your_facet_field2
```

where

**solrhost** - Solr address

**solrport** - Solr port (default 8983)

**your_facet_field1**, etc - your field msgs

**your_query** could be *:* if you want to facet every document

Result will be something like this:

```
<response>
   <responseHeader>
      <status>0</status>
      <QTime>2</QTime>
   </responseHeader>
   <result numFound="4" start="0" />
   <lst name="facet_counts">
      <lst name="facet_queries" />
      <lst name="facet_fields">
         <lst name="your_facet_field1">
            <int name="search">0</int>
            <int name="memory">0</int>
            <int name="graphics">0</int>
            <int name="card">0</int>
            <int name="music">1</int>
            <int name="software">0</int>
            <int name="electronics">3</int>
            <int name="copier">0</int>
            <int name="multifunction">0</int>
            <int name="camera">0</int>
            <int name="connector">2</int>
            <int name="hard">0</int>
            <int name="scanner">0</int>
            <int name="monitor">0</int>
            <int name="drive">0</int>
            <int name="printer">0</int>
         </lst>
         <lst name="your_facet_field2">
            <int name="false">3</int>
            <int name="true">1</int>
         </lst>
      </lst>
   </lst>
</response>
```

Comment: This is my query

select?q=msgs%3A*&fl=msgs&wt=xml&indent=true&facet=true&facet.query=msgs&facet.field=msgs&facet.limit=3

The output of facet count is similar to this.

word1 1600
word2 1536 
word3 956

Now in addition to that, I also want to display only the fields which contain the above words

Comment: so, could you give an example?

Comment: I dont know how to proceed from here on. I have to display the fields from the 'msgs' column which contain the word 'word1' and 'word2' and 'word3' separately

Comment: This is my sample output for the query

<result name="response" numFound="13492" start="0">
<doc>
<str name="msgs">
This is field1
</str>
</doc>
<doc>
<str name="msgs">
This is field 2
</str>
</doc>
<doc>
<str name="msgs">
This is field3
</str>
</doc>
</result>
<lst name="facet_counts">
<lst name="facet_queries">
<int name="msgs">9</int>
</lst>
<lst name="facet_fields">
<lst name="msgs">
<int name="word1">1600</int>
<int name="word2">1536</int>
<int name="word3">956</int>
</lst>
</lst>
<lst name="facet_dates"/>
<lst name="facet_ranges"/>
</lst>
</response>

Comment: As you can see, there are 13,492 records.. I want to display only the records which contain the above words i.e. word1, word2, word3.

So, I want to display 1600 records which contain word1

1536 records which contain word2

956 records which contain word3.